# Symfony Assert\Regex not catching comparing to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I am using Silex to validate a simple API.

For POST login, I use the symfony validation Assert classes however Assert\Regex is not working as planned.
Here is my constraints:

```
$constraints = new Assert\Collection(
    array(
        'username' => new Assert\Required(
            array(
                new Assert\NotNull(), 
                new Assert\NotBlank(), 
                new Assert\Email(array('strict'=>true)), 
                new Assert\Regex(array('pattern'=>'/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/'))
            )
        ),
        'password' => new Assert\Required(array(new Assert\NotNull(), new Assert\NotBlank())),
    )
);
```

This is not working and is allowing user@user''' to go through

However

```
 preg_match("/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/", $email, $matchResults);
 if (count($matchResults) === 0) {
    return false;
 }
```

the preg_match equivalent does catch it and rejects the email as non-valid.

Is there something that I am missing that the Assert\Regex treating the pattern as different than preg_match?

Comment: You can try getting rid of the regex delimiters: `'pattern'=>'^([a-z0-9_.-]+@[0-9a-z.-]+[.][a-z.]{2,6})$'`.